# installing ADT 17 on windows 7 and eclipse indigo, Everything works fine but there is no Android type project in New Project

Tags: android, adt

Today I installed the new Android SDK tools revision 17. When I started eclipse, it said that you should upgrade your ADT. I downloaded the latest version ZIP file (ADT-17.0.0.zip) and I followed the Eclipse instructions to install ADT. Everything goes fine (as I expected) but at the end I was unable to see Android in preferences and also android project in New Project wizard. 
I am using Eclipse Indigo and Windows 7.

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Libraries in SDK 17 - android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846586/libraries-in-sdk-17-android)

Answer (score 1):

Read this on android developer page under [Updating Plugin for Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#updating). I hope this helps.

> In some cases, a new revision of ADT will have a dependency on a specific revision of the Android SDK Tools. If such dependencies exist, you will need to update the SDK Tools component of the SDK after installing the new revision of ADT. To update the SDK Tools component, use the Android SDK and AVD Manager, as described in Adding SDK Components.
>
> If you encounter problems during the update, remove the existing ADT plugin from Eclipse, then perform a fresh installation, using the instructions for Installing the ADT Plugin.

Comment: I made a fresh installation of eclipse and SDK and ADT and nothing changed.

Comment: @Sergey Glotov I think the problem is that ADT (or eclipse) does not ask the place of Android SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Try running eclipse with `-clean` option from command line, like this:

```
C:\path_to_where_eclipse_is_installed\eclipse -clean
```

This should clean eclipse plugin preference caches, probably would resolve your case.

Answer (score 0):

Same experience for me.

Started with Mapview compile errors after getting the latest Java update 21Mar2012 though I hadn't changed path configs yet.

Loaded some SDK updates then following the suggestion from Eclipse Helio, found and updated to v17 of ADT. Path to Java on compile is broken yet Java compiler options have 1.6 as default.

Loaded Eclipse Indigo and loaded everything from scratch linked in latest Java update, same Java compile error.  You know something broken when Java.lang and String types are unknown...

Something seriously in error with V17 ADT and Windows eclipse.

Anyone know how to revert to previous ADT and SDK ?

ADDED:
When I looked at my other Android projects I noticed the Android 2.2 library class path was there (prev ADT versions).  The key to successful workaround changes seemed to be the `.classpath` files in the project workspace.

The workaround for me was to find a pre V17 file (below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

I then added the android and maps JARs manually under `Project > Properties > Java Build Path` and the file became:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con"   path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Apps/Android/android-sdk-windows/platforms/android-8/android.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Apps/Android/android-sdk-windows/add-ons/addon_google_apis_google_inc_8/libs/maps.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

This now works for me :)

Comment: Added google issue [Issue 27783](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27783) , found Android Jar dissappears in dependencies , adding External Jar causes Dalvik / Duplicate core error on debug launch.  Time to grow bananas or something, software dev is non existant ...

Comment: I had some serious issues with updating to ADT17 for all my projects.  My development setup at the time was with Eclipse Indigo.  After reading that ADT17 requires Helios (http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html), I removed Indigo...installed Helios....problems solved.  Very irritating to keep switching between Helios / Indigo.  I believe a previous update required me to do the opposite.  Why all this flip-flopping!  Took me 2 hours to get back to work after updating.  Shouldn't updates make things easier?!

Comment: @dell116 "Irritating" - massively agreeing with a steely smile. I ended up modifying the '.classpath' files in the workspace for Indigo and added all the Jars manually.  So I have Indigo working with Android ... ridiculous :/