# Libraries in SDK 17 - android

Tags: android, sdk

I have a question to which I have not found an answer, sorry if repeated
I upgraded to sdk and ADT 17 and since then every time I open a project leading, for example, advertising admob google gives me error:

Could not find class 'com.google.ads.AdView' ...

This strikes me in all projects that include libraries (jars)

I have read about in this SDK has changed something about it, but my English is not very good (use google translator) and I understand that I am doing wrong.

I appreciate any help.

Best regards

Answer (score 5):

[Quoting Xav](https://plus.google.com/u/0/109385828142935151413/posts/RL91VJd1yti):

> If you have ClassDefNotFoundError after updating to r17, make sure to read the following links:
>
> - http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17 shows how to fix the problem with nice pictures of what the project should look like.
> - http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects
>   (this was linked from the blog post and from the release notes) explains in detail how the new dependency system works.

Comment: If you have references to jars that are not in the ‘libs’ folder, for example if you use ‘classpath variable’, you can resolve the NoClassDefFoundError issue with the new ADT 17 by exporting the references.

To export the references: simply go to “Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export”, and check all the references you want exported.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after hours of research , I found a simple solution.

- Click on your Android Project
- Select Properties
- Select Java Build
- Path Select Order and Export
- Check all your references

Thats all !