# Referenced Libraries recent SDK/Eclipse Update Exception

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I just updated to Rev 17 SDK Tools and Rev 11 SDK Platform-tools and now none of my apps work.  Every single referenced Library that I have gives the error:

NoClassDefFoundError

Anyone know why?  I deleted and reinstalled the platform and tools but still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you cleaned your android library, and rebuild it,  and clean yoru other Android projects that uses this library, then restart Eclipse, then compile your project.

Comment: Yes, cleaned, restarted, and reran

Comment: Also tried deleting metadata in the workspace and reimporting

Comment: have you updated ADT plugin for Eclipse too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Libraries in SDK 17 - android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846586/libraries-in-sdk-17-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From here (comment):

[Libraries in SDK 17 - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846586/libraries-in-sdk-17-android)

Directs you to here:

http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

and the answer is in the comment

If you have references to jars that are not in the ‘libs’ folder, for example if you use ‘classpath variable’, you can resolve the NoClassDefFoundError issue with the new ADT 17 by exporting the references.

To export the references: simply go to “Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export”, and check all the references you want exported.