# Dalvikvm Cant find imported Class (org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration)

Tags: android, xmpp

If I run any example Like:

http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/

(http //android.codeandmagic.org/2011/10/small-test-of-asmack-xmpp-client-library/)

http://vidorsolutions.blogspot.com/2011/01/writing-xmppjabber-chat-application-for.html

in Eclipse i get this error:

```
E/dalvikvm(289): Could not find class 'org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration', referenced from method com.developpez.florentgarin.android.ClientJabberActivity.initConnection
```

The Referenced Method changed depending on the example. Since I'm extremely new to developing on anything not just android, I really have no clue why this is happening. On an old install of Win7 and eclipse, these examples worked fine. Now on a CLEAN install (Win7, JDK, Eclipse, Android SDK), It wont work at all.

If someone could help me point out what I could be doing wrong...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Libraries in SDK 17 - android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846586/libraries-in-sdk-17-android), if by "clean" you mean you reinstalled stuff in the past 48 hours or so...

Comment: THANK YOU, Ive been looking for answer since last night, That did it!. Thanks CommonsWare!