# Android Test Project with external libraries in ADT17

Tags: android, adt, android-library, android-testing

I've a main project that depends on other Library projects that use external JARS (that are also used in the main project).

Now with ADT17 I have removed from the main project the external libraries that are also used in library projects, because they are automatically inherited from new AD17 **Android dependencies** (from library projects).

Until here all works correctly. The problem is when I want to create a Test project for the main project. What I do is mark all externals jars and android dependencies as exportable to be inherited in the test project.
But the problem is that Android dependencies although they are market as exportable aren't inherited from the test project and when I run it I get some Link of class X not found... make sure it's in the apk.

I attach an image to make it more clear:

*(It's an snapshot from main project libraries. Blue marked ones are correctly inherited and red ones not).*

[image: Libraries from the main project. Blue ones are correctly inherited in test project, red ones not]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Libraries in SDK 17 - android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846586/libraries-in-sdk-17-android)

Comment: Not exactly the same. This question is related to test projects and the other question no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it was a bug in ADT17 with test projects that depend on external libraries.
Today I've updated to ADT18 and it works correctly without having any lib defined in test project.