# Eclipse Android SDK - error in building workspace

Tags: android, eclipse

I have updated my packages using Android SDK Manager and clicked on Help > Check for updates and updated installed plug-ins. I was prompted to restart eclipse, and now after restarting,

I get following Error code

```
'Building workspace' has encountered a problem.
Errors occurred during the build

Errors occurred during the build.
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
Bad version number in .class file
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sure to have the correct [dependencies](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)? Which eclipse version do you have installed? Which JRE/JDK is used to run eclipse with?

`Bad version number` means that there is a mismatch between the intended target java version and the one you use (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2466828/1262542)).

Comment: Before making these updates, my environment was fine. I have Eclipse version: 3.6.2 installed. In Window> Preferences, JDK compiler compliance level is 1.6. How can I correct the java version mismatch? I referred to the link you have provided but I do not know what to do.

Comment: The intended one is stated in the first link I posted (1.6). You can find the one you are using with the command `java -version`. However, the Eclipse launcher can use any VM installed, so perhaps this will not give the right answer.

It looks like ADT 17.0.0 is the first one requiring Java 1.6.

Comment: After searching online for some time, I think the problem is with ADT version 17, as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829008/installing-adt-17-on-windows-7-and-eclipse-indigo-everything-works-fine-but-the).

Comment: Looks a bit different, though you should upgrade the SDK, too. Hmm, up to now I used ADT 16 myself and updated to ADT 17. The ADT directly warned me to update the SDK as well; well, I'm on MacOS X right now...

Comment: I am on Windows Vista, I first updated SDK and then ADT. But I now also tried to update SDK, and it doesn't fix the problem. Looks like a google issue is reported [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27783).

Comment: Yes could be. Nevertheless, can you please check the `eclipse.ini` (should be located in $ECLIPSE root) file and post if there is a `-vm` entry? Perhaps this is pointing to the wrong VM.

Comment: My eclipse.ini file has the following contents `-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.5.0_22/bin/javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m`

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefan, it worked! I changed the -vm to point to the jre6 in place of jre1.5.0_22.

Comment: Nice to hear that. FYI perhaps you want to update to [Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), while you're at updating ;)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error. I checked for sdk updates again, installed them and in eclipse, i checked for updates(help->check for updates).
After reopening eclipse, i am back to normal now. hope this helps

Comment: the solution after 2 hours of searching. You might run into lib issues with ADT > v. 22 --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22

Answer (score 0):

In my case computer restart resolved all the issues without re-installing ADT plugin.
BTW, I am using MAC + ADT_v22

Answer (score 0):

> I have some error in one of my Project. I simply `switch` **Workspace** and the problem solved.

Open **Eclipse**. Go to **File Menu->Switch Workspace -> Other and create a new workspace path.** And you are good to go.