# android build failure in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, build, sdk

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt" was unable to instantiate class "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder  ".
com/android/sdklib/build/RenderScriptProcessor$CommandLineLauncher
Plug-in "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt" was unable to instantiate class "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder  ".
com/android/sdklib/build/RenderScriptProcessor$CommandLineLauncher
```

my sdk
sdk tools 22.3
build tools 19
platform-tools 19
target=android-15

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33209027/4260932

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

Right click your project, Select --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path --> Under the 'order and export' tab, make sure 'Android Private Libraries' is selected

**Option 2**

Goto Help --> Check for updates. Install any new updates

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you just need to restart eclipse by using:
**file/Restart**,and wait until all the libraries are loading.